# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL using java httpservlet on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I keep getting HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL when calling my httpservlet through an html form. I can't see where I'm going wrong.  I'm running this on a Tomcat server.  Thanks in advance.

The servlet is supposed to print a set of random numbers to the browser.

Here is my servlet:

```
package servlets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import utilities.RandNumSet;

public class RandomServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public RandomServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    TreeSet<Integer> randNum = RandNumSet.generateRandNumSet();
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = randNum.iterator();
    String numString = "";
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        numString = numString + iterator.next() + " ";
    }


    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>");
    out.println("Your Random Numbers!");
    out.println("</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1> Your Random Numbers! </h1>");
    out.println("<h1> "+ numString + " </h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
}

}
```

Here is the calling html form snippet:

```
<div id ="form">
    <form action="RandomServlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Randomize!"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here are the web.xml snippets

```
    <servlet>
        <display-name>RandomServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>RandomServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.RandomServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RandomServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RandomServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Strange, I recreated your scenario and it worked for me. Can you see if get works by adding something like this to your html page: <a href="RandomServlet">Try get</a>

Comment: I get basically the same thing Except now its "GET is not supported by this URL".  Ill look at your git Kharyam

Comment: Yep tried it and it didn't work. It should work.  At least I'm not going crazy.  Maybe there is a problem with my Tomcat configuration. Thanks

Comment: Nope, you're not going crazy. Are you using tomcat 7?

Comment: Just deleted and reinstalled Tomcat and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following way and its works...

first: check the directory first you have made like-

```
com.ServletExample 
|-JavaResource 
   |-src
      |-com.servletExample
          |-RandomServlet.java 
   |-WebContent
      |-META-INF
      |-WEB-INF
          |-Lib
          |-web.xml
   |-index.jsp
```

second: index.jsp is here

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="form">
    <form action="RandomServlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Randomize!"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

third: RendomServlet.java is here

```
package com.servletExample;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RandomServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public RandomServlet() {
super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/html");

out.println("<head>");
out.println("<title>");
out.println("Your Random Numbers!");
out.println("</title>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>");
out.println("<h1> Your Random Numbers! </h1>");
out.println("<h1> " + "Hello" + " </h1>");
out.println("</body>");
}

}
```

fourth: web.xml is here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JSPExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <display-name>RandomServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>RandomServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servletExample.RandomServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RandomServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RandomServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I hope this will work.